# How to match key words in a pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I want to iterate over all the rows in one of my Dataframe columns named **Subject** and look for multiple key words from the dictionary named **keywords**. If a key from the dictionary matches a word in the Dataframe column, I want to add the dictionary value pair for the matched key to a new column in the Dataframe named **Category**. My code below was my first idea to add values to a list and then add the list as a new column to my Dataframe but obviously the indexes will not match up. Is there a way to append the keyword value directly to the Dataframe whenever a key matches in the subject column?

'''

```
tickets = pd.read_csv('All VS Tickets with Category.csv',parse_dates=['Creation Date'])
tickets = tickets.fillna('')

keywords = {'BOR':'Broker of Record','New Vendor':'New Vendor Build'}
Category_column = []

def indexmatch(subject):
    for key, value in keywords.items():
        if key in subject:
            print('Match')
            Category_column.append(values)
        else:
            print('No Match')
            Category_column.append('')


tickets['Subject'].apply(indexmatch)
Category_column = pd.Series(Category_column)
tickets.insert(0,column='Category',value=Category_column)
```

'''

[Image of example code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BExTA.png)

Comment: Please don’t share code/data as images. You can just have your function return a value from the `.apply()` by the way. Mind you that isn’t even necessary here, since I’m pretty sure you can just `.map()` with the dict directly.

Comment: Should I put together a quick answer with some relevant resources on `.map()` or a basic explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `extract` your joined keywords and then `map`:

```
keywords = {'BOR':'Broker of Record','New Vendor':'New Vendor Build'}

df = pd.DataFrame({"Category":["Something BOR","Something New Vendor","Something for nothing"]})

df["new"] = df["Category"].str.extract(f"({'|'.join(keywords)})",expand=False).map(keywords)

print (df)

                Category               new
0          Something BOR  Broker of Record
1   Something New Vendor  New Vendor Build
2  Something for nothing               NaN
```

Comment: If I have touple values in the keywords:

Comment: keywords = {'New Vendor': ('New Vendor Build', 1.0),'BOR ': ('Broker of Record', '')'} is there a way to .map() and specify the first or second value in the tuple?

Comment: `....map(keywords).str[0]`. Also you can accept the answer if it solved your problem.